# Имя функции в JNI

Tags: jni, java, c, c++

Каким образом формируется имя функции для JNI, чтобы быть видимым из Java кода? Почему имя такое сложное?

> `Java_com_example_sample_SampleView_renderSample`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Назначение имени видно из самого имени:
класс *com.example.sample.SampleView*, метод *renderSample*.

Общий вид:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName
   (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
     /*Implement Native Method Here*/
 }
```

См. [спецификацию JNI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html), раздел "Resolving Native Method Names".